# Mac shell script - using a boolean value straight from a condition check

Tags: macos, bash, shell, osx-mountain-lion

I am writing a shell script to toggle the display of hidden files on Mac OSX Mountain Lion. But after searching around, I couldn't find an answer to this: Is it possible to take the boolean of a condition expression and use it straight? For example in java, I would have done `print(1 == 0)` and get the result `false`. If it is possible, how?

Please note that I am not asking for the "if-else" method that I only could find on Google. Below is the current script that I have wrote so far, with problems in line 2.

```
#!/bin/sh
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles [$(defaults read com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles) = 0]
killall Finder && open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not possible directly.

You could do something silly like

```
#!/bin/sh
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles $(defaults read com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles | grep -q 0 && echo true || echo false)
killall Finder && open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```

but it's best to just use if..then or a switch:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$(defaults read com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles)" in
  1) val=true ;;
  *) val=false ;;
esac
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles $val
killall Finder && open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```

Comment: I just found a solution and it was actually possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to the question after I discovered the "expr" command. It is actually possible.
`expr $(commandToCheck) = $(valueToCheckAgainst)` will return a standard output of 1 if true, 0 if false.

I have updated my code to the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles $(expr $(defaults read com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles) = 0)
```